# How to put array indexes on PHP string

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have following array:

```
Array
(
[WEEK_DAYS] => Array
    (
        [DEF] => Array
            (
                [0] => 08:00
                [1] => 20:00
            )

        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 08:01
                [1] => 20:01
            )
    )

[EXCEPTS] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2016-5-30
        [1] => 2016-6-20
        [2] => 2016-5-25
        [3] => 2016-6-5
    )
)
```

And following string on PHP:

```
 $form = <<<END
      <input class="form-control" name="title" type="text" id="title" value="$formData['WEEK_DAYS']['DEF'][0]">
 END;
```

When i use from this structure it will return error, how i can put this array index in my string. i can put it on variable and use from that variable but my indexes is too much and it take resource from server.

I see

> **Parse error**:  syntax error, unexpected ''
>   (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING ) or
>   variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) error

Comment: I have tried your code its working fine.

Comment: I see <b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING
) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

Comment: You should put your variables inside curly braces like this: `value="{$formData['WEEK_DAYS']['DEF'][0]}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use proper quotes in `$form`.

```
$arr = Array
(
"WEEK_DAYS" => Array
    (
        "DEF" => Array
            (
                0 => "08:00",
                1 => "20:00"
            ),
        0 => Array
            (
                0 => "08:01",
                1 => "20:01"
            )
    ));

echo $arr["WEEK_DAYS"]["DEF"][0];
$form = '<input class="form-control" name="title" type="text" id="title" value="'.$arr['WEEK_DAYS']['DEF'][0].'">';
```

Use `{}` for structure.

```
$form = <<<END
      <input class="form-control" name="title" type="text" id="title" value="{$formData['WEEK_DAYS']['DEF'][0]}">
 END;
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: thank you but i am force to use <<< structure and can not define like you($form = '')

Comment: check my edited code. @MajidAbbasi